# Type aliases with generics exhibit different behavior from non-generic type

Tags: typescript, generics, metaprogramming

Consider the following code:

```
type TestTuple = [
    { test: "foo" },
    {
        test: "bar";
        other: 1;
    }
];

type Foo<Prop extends string> = TestTuple extends Record<Prop, string>[]
    ? true
    : false;
type X = Foo<"test">;

type Prop = "test";
type Y = TestTuple extends Record<Prop, string>[]
    ? true
    : false;

// X is type false
const x: X = false;
// Y is type true
const y: Y = true;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwYFcwBtoF4oG0BQUhUA3lMAsAFxQBEAZgPYM1QC+ANAUcV0UeYmo0ARgEMATjQDcvPlAbAAFhHHUAjDL6s8AXRl5QkKADEmAHgAK4hmCgQAHuQB2AE3hRE4gJZOA5gD4obDhEFHRoB2c3KAAlCABjBnEXS2swdg9gbz9-HB1ZAH4ycWQIWWo6UTR4CBlDaAANIJNzGgFgGn99eqgrG2a2imkDcGgATWaQpFQMO0cIV3c4xOTUmwzPHwC8wuLS8qhK6tq8PAB6M6gmr3ceo5q8RKdEKHtqJux7k4uoCZuyUZ7MpPF4gagTbBZUoyIA).

Types `Foo` and `Y` are the exact same, except `Foo` has a generic parameter `Prop`, whereas `Y` just uses a type alias called `Prop` (the type alias isn't required, `Y` could just be `TestTuple extends Record<"test", string>[] ? true : false` but I wanted to make their declarations exactly the same). So, `Foo<"test">` (which is aliased into the type `X`) and `Y` should have the same types, right? Apparently not. `X` as type `false` whereas `Y` is type `true`. Changing the `other` property in `TestTuple` to a string or removing the property altogether causes both `X` and `Y` to be true, which is the expected behavior.

So, my question is: why is this? Is this a bug in the compiler? If so, has an issue already been filed that I've been unable to find? Or, is this some weird way that generics are handled in typescript?

Comment: Wow, this is interesting. I haven't definitively found an existing issue yet; possibly [microsoft/TypeScript#30152](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30152) or one of its related issues? If you do file a bug about this, I'd suggest stripping it down to the smallest code example that shows it, such as `type What<K extends string> = { x: { y: 0, z: 1 } } extends { x: { [P in K]: 0 } } ? true : false;`.  That type is eagerly reduced to `type What<K extends string> = false` no matter what you put in for `K`, even though `What<"y">` should be `true`. [link](https://tsplay.dev/YmpdBm)

Comment: Still investigating... possibly [microsoft/TypeScript#39364](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39364) is the same issue.  Posted a comment there and I'll see if anyone with compiler wisdom replies

Comment: I find it strange that wrapping the object in `{x: obj}` somehow affects the behavior. It seems that the mere presence of a generic causes the compiler to start acting weird.

Comment: FYI, this bug has been fixed for TS4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: This has been fixed for TypeScript 4.2: [Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-dev.20201202#code/PTAEDcBYDoCZoAwFoAmBTccGwQRh7AFAAuAngA5qgDqAFgIbEA8A0qGgB7FoB2KAzqH7EATgEseAcwB8oALyFQS0AG9QHAFyrQpLQgA0oAF5bcoAL4X2XXgO2btAbQAKoCaBYBdPVcsB+UFEAVyotADN6ABt+NABuEgoqAAkg2nkaBmYAIlIs2RBAkRDCQiA)

---

I've filed [microsoft/TypeScript#41613](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41613) about this, after reducing to the following minimal example:

```
type What<K extends string> =
    { x: { y: 0, z: 1 } } extends { x: { [P in K]: 0 } } ? true : false;

type Huh = What<"y">; // expect true but got false!
```

Lead architect for TypeScript [Anders Hejlsberg](https://github.com/ahejlsberg) has [commented](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39364#issuecomment-731302182):

> When determining whether to defer resolution of the conditional type we relate the "most permissive instantiations" of the check and extends types. The constraint of the most permissive instantiation of the extends type ends up being `{ x: { [index: string]: 0 } }`, but really it should be `{ x: { } }`. It's a simple fix and I'll include it in this PR.

So hopefully it will end up fixed in [a new PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/41622) and possibly merged into TypeScript by TypeScript 4.2. (Update: it has been merged.)  And if so, I expect this should address the issue in your question, where instead of wrapping the indexed type with `{x: ...}`, we are wrapping it with a tuple type.

Until then, you should consider using a workaround like the one in [@Temoncher's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64923162/2887218).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.2#code/PTAEGEHsDsGcEsAmBTATgKAC4E8AOzQB1ACwENMAeAaVGQA9NlpFZRZNV5oBzAPlAC86UCNABvUHQBc40NhkAGADSgAXjICMoAL47aDJi1nTZAbQAKoLqCoBdRXt0B+UBwCuBGQDNSAG1jIANzo6CCgAJJecpBuoL6QkADWoOSuxAQAjm7wAMaJXF6QoOmoyCrwmKDcyJisyKTVqL7YbPAAtri+8F7wyIiuRaFgOPhEZJQ09IzMrOycPPwCoD7+yCFhAEZulZjjrW3wnd255PAwVqzQkJU5kKilOZgqCNA5BCTkFABE2F-8sMQYr5+hsCMgsvAAG5+Jg7SBDYwyCTyUDKNSaRz6aZGCQmZEOXTOVyoDygbx+AIIgDuxFyxAuxI8KiulRWlIRAGUirsCIVfPEqVxuHEuARcKhIIg3G9WG5oPR8I8+qBSrA3L5alg8AQABJuelLD6UH5-UBhNlrIYga02212+0Ox1O4DrMAAFVprHFkA2vmQbSqkGQrFIVNILW6oCpBDlVNQpFwaQIdDi4bQUmEWtGAHlEuHqFjDLMOELFsJRPjUSp1KAtLopkWzJZrHYCaAXO5PMsKUFXWl4KwB6AWbQGmhmvsjj0+ipSMw2PCswQAIL8gBK8G4xEqS1z+ZN-DCnZCQA)

Comment: Interesting. I guess I'll have to save my type shenanigans for after this bug gets fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I personally have no idea. It has something to do with dictionary types like `Record` or `{ [K in Prop]: any }`, because in my experience it fails only for these. Hope someone can come up with better answer.

But I can offer a workaround.

#### Workaround

Instead of comparing `TestTuple` with `Record<...>[]`, compare `TestTuple[number]` with `Record<...>`

```
type Foo<P extends string> = TestTuple[number] extends Record<P, string>
  ? true
  : false
// true
type X = Foo<'test'>

// also true
type Y = TestTuple extends Record<'test', string>[]
    ? true
    : false;
```